# Change in Cookie information, when read from PHP

Tags: php, javascript, cookies

My problem is this. I'm setting a cookie using java script, which contains value

```
"MXGWJfgr4HDINl/BdAfBUf12710aFNcaIQKgGJ7VShxvprVo1XK+Hntg"
```

Now, when i receive and read this cookie on a PHP page, im getting the content as

```
"MXGWJfgr4HDINl/BdAfBUf12710aFNcaIQKgGJ7VShxvprVo1XK Hntg"
```

The '+' sign is change to a space character. Why is it so?

Comment: Something is URL encoding (or URL decoding) the cookie contents. What code are you using on each end?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php#88803

Comment: i dont use any URI encoding. Just setting it as doucment.cookie=name="value"; Sorry i'm a newbie to this.

Comment: @dev: I cannot set the cookie from PHP. coz i'm setting it from javascript with a value i fetch using a webservice from a java back end. I display the page from java backend.

Comment: Try storing `encodeURIComponent("MXGWJfgr4HDINl/BdAfBUf12710aFNcaIQKgGJ7VShxvprVo1XK+Hntg")` in the cookie.

Comment: http://cass-hacks.com/articles/discussion/js_url_encode_decode/

Check that link. It says some problems regarding encodings. It might solve your problem

Comment: try to use html_entity_decode(your_cookie) php function when you read from cookie variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [document.cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.cookie) reference:

> The cookie value string can use encodeURIComponent() to ensure that
>   the string does not contain any commas, semicolons, or whitespace
>   (which are disallowed in cookie values).

So this is what you need to do:

```
document.cookie = "foobar=" + encodeURIComponent("MXGWJfgr4HDINl/BdAfBUf12710aFNcaIQKgGJ7VShxvprVo1XK+Hntg");
alert(document.cookie); // + becomes %2B which PHP will interpret and decode automatically
```

Comment: Thanks for that precise answer